# Create Columns in a datatable with a single expression

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to define a datatable with columns, where the column definition is *part* of the datatable definition statement.

Eg

```
//valid syntax
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.add("num",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.add("num2",typeof(int));
```

But I would rather want to do something along the lines of

```
//invalid syntax
DataTable dt = new DataTable(Data.Columns[] {
    {"num",typeof(int)},
    {"num2",typeof(int)}
};
```

Is this possible? 
If it is, what is the correct syntax.

Comment: You have to write that yourself. This is simple enough with a static method that returns your new DataTable, or you could employ a decorator pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't initialize DataTable with collection initializer. All you can use is `AddRange` method of `DataColumnCollection`, but I don't think its much better than your original approach

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new[] {
    new DataColumn("num", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("num2", typeof(int))
});
```

You can create extension method which will add columns in fluent way:

```
public static DataTable AddColumn<T>(this DataTable dt, string name)
{
     dt.Columns.Add(name, typeof(T));
     return dt;
}
```

Usage:

```
var dt = new DataTable()
          .AddColumn<int>("num")
          .AddColumn<int>("num2");
```